# mvn spring-boot:run fails

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Spent a lot of time on this issue. Couldn't find and way to fix this issue on my own. I tried deleting my local repo and reinstall, adding plugin repositories in my pom etc... To my surprise I have another project which uses same spring-boot-maven-plugin 1.2.3 and that project doesn't error out but run fine.

Running `mvn spring-boot:run` errors out `No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups`

running with mvn -e option shows an exception below

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/auhuman/.m2/repository)
```

But my local repository has this plugin as below.

```
ls ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.2.3.RELEASE/

_remote.repositories                    spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar.sha1     spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.2.3.RELEASE.pom.sha1
spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar      spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.2.3.RELEASE.pom
spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar.lastUpdated  spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.2.3.RELEASE.pom.lastUpdated
```

my pom.xml has

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you did not run "mvn spring-boot:run" under the directory that contains the pom.xml with spring-boot.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if there is a `spring-boot` folder in `/Users/auhuman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot`?

If not try to run `mvn clean install`

Comment: Yes. It is there. ls ~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/
spring-boot   spring-boot-starter-cache
spring-boot-actuator  spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
spring-boot-autoconfigure spring-boot-starter-jdbc
spring-boot-dependencies spring-boot-starter-logging
spring-boot-loader-tools spring-boot-starter-parent
spring-boot-maven-plugin spring-boot-starter-test
spring-boot-parent  spring-boot-starter-tomcat
spring-boot-starter  spring-boot-starter-web
spring-boot-starter-actuator spring-boot-starters
spring-boot-starter-amqp spring-boot-tools
spring-boot-starter-aop